# How will we get the id of a particular <ul> in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the jquery function which makes the ul draggable and and a particular area droppable.
//Jquery

```
$(function () {
    // there's the gallery5 and the trash
    var $gallery5 = $("#gallery5"),
        $trash = $("#trash");
    // let the gallery5 items be draggable
    $("ul", $gallery5).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
    });
    // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
    $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        accept: "#gallery2 > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("trash");
            deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
    $gallery5.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery li , #gallery2 li , #gallery4 li , #gallery3 li",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("gallery5");
            recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    // image deletion function
    var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

    // image recycle function
    var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

    function recycleImage ($item) {
    //  alert("recycleImage");
        $item.fadeOut(function () {
            $item
                .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
                .remove()
                .end()
                .css("width", "250px")
                .find("img")
                .css("height", "50px")
                .end()
                .fadeIn()
                .appendTo($gallery5);
        });
    }

    // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
});
```

This is called in a loop and the data is coming from the database.
//BODY

```
<ul id=coming from database> 
    <li>
            description
            id              
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are multiple uls in the output. I want to check the id of that particular ul which i am dragging.
Thanx.

Comment: have you tried `this.id` or `this.attr("id")`?

Comment: yes i tried. it is not working. thanx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var ulID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

This will get the ID from each ul, you can then do what you need with it . . .

Comment: If you need to target a specific ID it's simply $('#specificID') - is this what you mean ?

Comment: actually no. that specific id can be anything, it is coming from the database. i am actually dragging a <ul>, so i want to know which <ul> i am dragging. i kno where it is going but i dont know which one is going. thanx!

Comment: In your '$("ul", $gallery5).draggable({' function, $(this).attr('id') should return the specific ID of the UL.

Comment: hi, sorry but i didnt get you.

Comment: Sorry, possibly I was getting mixed up. Somewhere, you'll have a handler that fires when a ul is clicked (to start the drag), within that function, you can refer to $(this).attr('ul') which will return the ID of the ul that has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try this:

```
var ids = '';
$('ul').each(function(){
  ids += $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  $('ul').each(function()
        {
           var ids= $(this).attr('id'); // This is your rel value
        });
```